# Magento2: unable to override methods in Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection

Tags: product-collection, magento-2.2.5, override-model

I want to override the model class(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php)

Flow the below process to override the addUrlRewrite method but not working.

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="MyModule\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
</config>
```

**Collection.php**

```
<?php
    namespace MyModule\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Product;

    class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
    {

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
            \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
            \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
            \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl,
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null
        ) {
            parent::__construct(
                    $entityFactory,
                    $logger,
                    $fetchStrategy,
                    $eventManager,
                    $eavConfig,
                    $resource,
                    $eavEntityFactory,
                    $resourceHelper,
                    $universalFactory,
                    $storeManager,
                    $moduleManager,
                    $catalogProductFlatState,
                    $scopeConfig,
                    $productOptionFactory,
                    $catalogUrl,
                    $localeDate,
                    $customerSession,
                    $dateTime,
                    $groupManagement,
                            $connection
                );


        }
         public function addUrlRewrite($categoryId = '')
        {
            echo '<pre>';exit(var_dump("Hello Test"));
        }



    }
```

Please, can you help on above issue? any references and suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to modify any functions in the sense then you don't need constructor unless you want any class to inject and used anywhere in your code @Parthavi

Comment: What you want to achieve by overriding this method?

Answer (score 0):

> In **module.xml** add this :-

```
<sequence>
   <module name="Magento_Catalog"/> 
   <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>         
   <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
   <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
   <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
   <module name="Magento_Vault"/>
   <module name="Magento_OfflineShipping"/>           
</sequence>
```

> Or you Can Use Plugin For Override `addUrlRewrite` function

put below code in **`Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml`**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
    <plugin name="product-collection-addurlrewrite" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\Collection" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Create **`Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\Collection.php`** and pasted below code in your file:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product;

class Collection
{

    public function (typeofplugin(after,before,around))addUrlRewrite(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject)
    {
         // do your stuff here
        return $result;
    }
}
```